# how to make a bootstrap datepick button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, button, datepicker

as the title says, I want to make a **bootstrap datepicker** which will show up when a user clicks on a **button**. I have been searching for some tutorial for whole 2 days and found only tutorials for datepickers with input. The only site which shows that it is possibe is [this one.](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)
Unfortunately there is not shown the code for it. That is why I am here. I hope you guys can help me from my desperation :)

Comment: You have provided no code and no effort. Please make an attempt....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is extracted from the [Bootstrap Datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) website you linked above, and adapted to use a button instead of a button-like link-element: http://jsfiddle.net/VchBF/

HTML:

```
<button class="btn small" id="button" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" data-date="2012-02-20">Your Date Picker</button>
```

JS:

```
$('#button').datepicker()
.on('changeDate', function(ev){
    $('#button').datepicker('hide');
    alert(ev.date.valueOf());
});
```

Comment: its just the datepicker not the example :(

Comment: hm, it show the calendar in the topleft corner, like it didnt knew where to paint it :/

Comment: Are you looking at the jsfiddle? Which browser are you using?

Comment: hm, in jsfiddle it works well but when copy paste it to my code it wont even show the calendar. I had to do that with onclick function. Im using chrome

Answer (score 2):

This is What I did With Jquery

Steps :
  In html file paste this

```
<input type="text" id="your-datepicker-id" style="display: none;">
```

In JS file paste this

```
$('#your-datepicker-id').datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy", 
  showOn: "button",
  buttonText: '<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>'
})
```

Output Will Be A Button

```
<button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-trigger"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
```

Extras :

You Can Add bootstrap Classes as

```
$(".ui-datepicker-trigger").addClass("btn btn-success")
```

You Can also do ajax calls as

```
$('#your-datepicker-id').datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy", 
  showOn: "button",
  buttonText: '<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>',
  onSelect: function (dateText) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "script",
        url: your_url
    })
  }
})
```

Note:  (dateText == Date Which is Selected)

This is the output i Got

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define the markup for your input..

```
<div class="container">
<div class="input-append date" id="dp3" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
  <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012" id="myDate">
  <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
</div>
```

And then use jQuery to use the datetime picker on the input..

```
$('#myDate').datepicker();
```

Here's a working example: http://bootply.com/86820

Comment: thanks for the answer.  but actually it is not what I wanted. This makes the input and a button(icon). I just want it to make only a button.